# BaseAdapter GetView With Condition

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am stuck at a very minor error ,
I want to place a condition inside the getview of the Baseadapter class.
If the condition is true it should not inflate ,else it should inflate in the listview.

Some help would be really appreciated

This is my code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidelistrow, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        if(resultp.get(MainFragment.TAG_PACKAGE).equals(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME))
        {
            return null;
        }else
        {
            return itemView;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong. `getView` can not return null, otherwise your application will crash. What you have to do is to submit the exact dataset you want show, it means that your `data` has to contains exactly what you want to show in the `ListView`